# "all" or "index,follow" in robots meta tag?

Tags: web-crawler, seo, meta-tags

Is this a correct way to allow the Google bot to crawl our website?

```
<meta name="robots" content="all"/>
```

What is better to allow the Google bot by using?

```
<meta name="robots" content="all"/>
```

or

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
```

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this somewhere.

Comment: Related: *[What is the difference between "index, follow" or "follow"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277433/)*

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 2):

You don't explicitly need a meta tag to allow Google to crawl your site, although it doesn't hurt to have one.  Because neither has an advantage over the other use `content="all"` to trim off the few extra bytes of transfer.

Documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag#directives
- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/special-tags